# Bash Scripting: parsing a string delimited with commas

Tags: bash

I have a file that has a lot of words in it, one on each line. I also have a second file that has words all on one line delimited by commas. What I am trying to do is access each word that is delimited by commas. Once I have each word I want to remove that word for the file in the first file.

I am having trouble accessing each word in the delimited file.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# split_comma
OIFS=$IFS
IFS=','

for w in $(cat $1)
do
    # Do stuff with each word
    echo $w
done

IFS=$OIFS
```

---

`$ ./split_comma test_file` where `test_file` contains `this,is,a,test` returns:

```
this
is
a
test
```

You could then easily use `grep` to filter the words out of the larger, line-separated file.

Comment: Minor quibble (that someone once pointed out to me): if `IFS` was *unset* originally, it is set to the empty string afterwards. Fix with `${IFS-:} OIFS=$IFS` and `${OIFS-:} IFS=$OIFS`.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
grep -w -v -f <(tr ',' '\n' < 2nd_file) 1st_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like this:

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/g' fileWithCommas > tempfile
grep -v -f tempfile wordfile > newfile && mv newfile wordfile
rm tempfile
```